# How to hide cursor while recording screen on ChromeOS while keeping it visible to user?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, screen-recording

I am developing a screen recorder for ChromeOS which has a requirement that while recording the cursor should be visible to the user but it should have been hidden in the video after recording.

I know I can hide the cursor while recording by setting the pointer's icon to something invisible, but it will make the cursor invisible to user.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Same concern with developing android .apk app which also can run on Chromebook